# SQL dependency event not being triggered

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sqldependency

First time working with SQL Dependency... but after having gone over several examples I feel as I am doing everything correct. I've checked that the Broker is Enabled. I've further checked that my query is correct. I am not receiving any exceptions at all! All and all everything seems as it should work... but it is not, and I have no idea how to begin to troubleshoot it without any exceptions being thrown.

Any help would be VERY much appreciated!

Here is my class:

```
public class NotificationEvent
{
    private delegate void RateChangeNotification(DataTable table);
    private SqlDependency dependency;
    string ConnectionString = @"ConnectionString";
    string UserName = Environment.UserName;

    public async void StartNotification()
    {
        SqlDependency.Start(this.ConnectionString, "UserNotificationsQueue");
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString);
        await connection.OpenAsync();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();           
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT [NotificationID],[UserFrom],[UserTo],[DateTimeSent],[Notification] FROM [dbo].[PersonnellNotifications]", UserName);
        command.Notification = null;


        this.dependency = new SqlDependency(command, "Service=PostUserNotificationsQueue;", Int32.MaxValue);
        dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(this.SqlDependencyOnChange);
        await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
    }

    private void SqlDependencyOnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (eventArgs.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Invalid)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The above notification query is not valid.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Notification Info: " + eventArgs.Info);
            Console.WriteLine("Notification source: " + eventArgs.Source);
            Console.WriteLine("Notification type: " + eventArgs.Type);
        }
    }


    public void StopNotification()
    {
        SqlDependency.Stop(this.ConnectionString, "QueueName");
    }
}
```

I am initializing this from another classes IniatializeComponent() as seen:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    // Initialize SQL Dependancy        
    ne.StartNotification();
}
```

Comment: My familiarity with sql dependencies is rather limited, but I was wondering if you had connected SQL Profiler to see what you're actually doing on the server.

Comment: By design this initialization should occur Global.asax.Application_Start or Startup.cs.

Comment: @Programmer You are correct... I actually just switched it a few minutes ago following another issue. But even at the Startup Level it produced the same results.

Comment: Is this for signalR? If so, I have assisted in building this out for a couple clients by remoting to their machine. It is a complicated thing but if I know it is signalR then I would ask for you to add the Hub code.

Comment: @Programmer No it's not although SignalR would probably be better suited in what I am using the SQL Dependency for i.e. I am mimicking a messaging/ notification app. It is a simple WinForms Tray(NotifyIcon) application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tested following in my Code and Its working good. I have simplified your code. Please see if this is working and you are getting a call in OnNotificationChange on Db Change.

```
public async void RegisterForNotification()
{
     var connectionString = @"ConnectionString";
     using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
     {
         await connection.OpenAsync();

          var queryString = "Your Query String";
          using (var oCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
          {
              // Starting the listener infrastructure...
              SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);

               var oDependency = new SqlDependency(oCommand);
               oDependency.OnChange += OnNotificationChange;

               // NOTE: You have to execute the command, or the notification will never fire.
                await oCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            }
        }
    }


private void OnNotificationChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Notification Info: " + e.Info);
    //Re-register the SqlDependency. 
   RegisterForNotification();
}
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained why you think your code works while the OP's code does not.

Comment: Sweet! I've been spinning my wheels on this for hours. Any idea what I was doing wrong??

Comment: Also I wasn't aware that you had to re-register after the event is triggered? Is that necessary?

Comment: @AnthonyGriggs, You have to re-register SQL dependency every time a notification is triggered, SQL dependency only registers for one notification.

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting SQLClientPermission? see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-query-notifications

```
// Code requires directives to
// System.Security.Permissions and
// System.Data.SqlClient

private bool CanRequestNotifications()
{
    SqlClientPermission permission =
        new SqlClientPermission(
        PermissionState.Unrestricted);
    try
    {
        permission.Demand();
        return true;
    }
    catch (System.Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are correct... I was missing this. Unfortunately however it did not solve my issue.